# Plotting interactive (dom elements/objects) points using Java script (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a webpage, where I want to plot points with which I can associate Mouse events (Jquery).
So, I guess I want them to be dom objects and not want to just paint them. (Please suggest if we can paint using html5 and still treat them as dom elements)

So essentially I have a text files with x,y co-ordinates and I want to plot those but want to associate Jquery events with them. for example: on left clicking them a graph appears or right clicking them a menu appears depending on which node I clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho, it would be a very silly approach, to write DOM elements with lines and dots.. For instance, how would you make a round line - you *could* create diagonal lines with border CSS styling but.. Well - there are many options available! Another approach could be Highslide.

### jqueryui-visualize

[jQuery](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/) top5 graphing tools

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

[Demo](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/jqueryui-visualize/)

### Dojo Toolkit

Since you for some reason have tagged this with dojo, check out this blog entry;
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/27/dojo-charting-event-support-has-landed/

[2dChart Demo](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_event2d.html)

[Read about Scrolling / Zooming here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/15/zooming-scrolling-and-panning-in-dojo-charting/)

[Zoom Demo](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_win2d.html)

Here's a nice little [introduction slideshow](http://people.apache.org/%7Etonywu/Roadshow10/track1/Data%20Visualization%20with%20Dojo%20toolkit.ppt) from an apache user

Answer (score 1):

Well, several approaches.

You can take your coords and create absolute positioned elements on the DOM using those points. Using jQuery you can set 'top' and 'left' points to position them. This method may be easiest for you because jQuery can easily apply click events.

You can use the HTML5 canvas and draw shapes onto it using the coords from your file. With this method you would either need to write your own event library or use libraries already written such as kinetic.js. Also styling these is going to be a bit less dynamic and extensive than using DOM objects and CSS as with the first method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I do not really want these nodes to be dynamic but want to associate some actions with each. (I have data associated with each node) and clicking on the node I want to plot that data in top right corner.  Can you please suggest something other than kinetic.js which is more apt for the purpose as kinectic.js seems to be more for playing with elements.

Comment: I further want to connect these nodes with lines. And even those lines have to be clickable. I mean even with those connecting lines I want to associate mouse events.  And this whole network should be zoomable. Please suggest what will the right way .. Thanks again.

Comment: well if your going the route of the HTML5 canvas then I still would suggest kinetic. It gives you most all of the same mouse/keyboard events of jQuery but applies them to canvas shapes. Keep researching it yourself to find out more.

Comment: Thanks again. I am all together new to JS. So just one last quick question, (I know I would be searching on my own :(, instead of asking everything). Provided I want the functionality like zooming in/out the canvas. You think that can be achieved without going HTML 5 way  ?

Comment: I don't think you can elegantly achieve the zoom functionality without html5 (or flash which is a much worse alternative).
Besides kinect, there are many other graphic libraries. Check them out and you'll find the right one for your case.